# Systemd-boot doesn't show/detect Pop OS, only shows Windows

Tags: windows, dual-boot, systemd-boot

So, I have an Alienware from 2016 that I have dual-booted with Pop OS. Windows 11 is installed on an SSD in the SATA slot while Pop OS 22.04 is on the NVME slot.

After I start the computer, the PC does go to the systemd-boot manager. However, the only two options are "Windows Boot Manager" and "Reboot to firmware." Despite this, Pop OS can be accessed by hitting F12 at the BIOS to go to boot selection, and selecting the NVME which for some bizzare reason I'm not exactly sure of also says "Windows Boot Manager", but starts Pop OS. The SATA drive with Windows is also labeled as "Windows Boot Manager" on this screen but starts Windows 11.